# Desktop application and Secure REST API : OAuth2 vs WSSE?

Tags: api, rest, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

We need to develop a **desktop application** (installed on a computer) that need to access to **REST API** (over HTTP).

- This REST API must be accessible for **authorized users** only (registered users).
- We assume the installed application has access to the system browser.
- In the future,  REST API might be used by mobile device apps or third-party webapp.

**To handle REST API stateless authentication / authorization** from installed application , we heard of protocols `OAuth2` or `WSSE`, but we never experience..

After some investigation, It's yet confused. **Which protocol seems to make more sense here** ?
What's their differences / main similarities / constraints ? How to choose ? Is there one another best way?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 is what you want. I do not know more about WSSE than what is readily "Googlable" on the web - and it seems to be designed for SOAP APIs - not REST services. So stick to OAuth2 - there's quite a few articles about it on the web. Here is one http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2014/02/api-authentication-considerations-and.html which I wrote some time ago.